# If we cache params into a local var in an action, will it help or its the same?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, reek

So we run a code quality tool called [reek](http://wiki.github.com/kevinrutherford/reek) once in a while as part of our project. The tool basically looks for code smells and reports them. Here, we observed that we get "Duplication" smell every time we try to access a key in `params` more than once (As if we are making a method-call twice with same parameters or we are duplicating an if condition etc). However, `params` is just a `Hash`, right? Other hashes don't get duplication smell when their keys are accessed more than once.

Why is this so? What are `params` exactly? Does it make sense to cache `params` in a local variable then use them? Will it help or its the same? Or is there something wrong with the tool? Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the current version it's best to run Reek only on your app/models folder, because it raises false positives against views and controllers.

params is a kind of DTO (data transfer object) close to the system boundary, and so its characteristics should be different than regular code. But Reek doesn't know that (yet). I plan to improve Reek in the near future so that it plays better with Rails. For now though, your best bet is to restrict it to looking at app/models (and maybe app/helpers and lib).

Answer (score 2):

params is a method call that does a `@params ||= @request.params`

It might be that it thinks params is a complicated method, so it wants you to try and cache it in a variable, but, dont think that would be worth it especially since it is memoized (based on my rack_process.rb from Rails 2.2)

Comment: Thanks Omar. As Kevin pointed out, params being a kind of a DTO, its different than any other object and Reek doesn't know that yet.

Answer (score 0):

`params[:foo]` is a method-call to `Hash#[]`, so reek is correct. I'm not familiar with reek, so I can't tell why other Hash accesses don't get counted the same. `Hash#[]` should be fast enough that you don't need to store it in a local variable unless you're in a very performance critical part of your code.

The only difference between the params Hash and a regular Hash is that it uses `with_indifferent_access`, meaning you can access any key with a String or a Symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I believe every time you call params, there is an initialization step which generates method calls, i suppose you can try creating a params and checking number of calls.
this could be blind guess. :-)